# Preventing IAM users to create volume from ANY snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, volume, snapshot

I'm creating IAM policies for restricting access to EC2 resources.
I'm struggling with *CreateVolume* Action.
I have following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateTaggedVolumes",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Zone": "MyZone"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "Name",
                        "Zone"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateVolume"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have policies that allow user to create EC2 instances only in "MyZone" subnet and to attach *volumes* with tag:Zone=MyZone to *instances* with tag:Zone=MyZone.

The problem is that there is possible exploit using this approach:
User can create *volume* from any *snapshot* ( the one that admin'd created for example) and then attach it to his/her own EC2 *instance*. But Ideally he needs to be able to create volume only from snapshot marked with specific tag.

And AWS provides only *volume* resource for *CreateVolume* Action. Therefore I can not modify policy above to allow volume creation only from snapshot with specific tag or using any other *snapshot-related* condition.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: The [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon EC2 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html) page shows `ec2:ParentSnapshot` as a valid Condition. I wonder if you can use that?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, you're right,we can restrict snapshot using this condition but problem is valid value for it - it can be ARN. Maybe i'm wrong but as I know we can not specify _id_ when creating snapshots so I need to specify exactly what snapshot(s) is(are) allowed for volume creation. So I'll need to add ARNs to policy every time. And I want to permit users to use all snapshots that have tag:Zone=MyZone.